# How to get the calling method's name at runtime

Tags: ruby

I have:

```
def outer_method()
  called_method()
end

def called_method()
  puts "name of outer_method"
end
```

Is it possible for the `called_method` to get the name of the `outer_method` without assigning `__method__` in the `outer_method` and then using it as an argument of `called_method`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. An old school way is to go like this:

```
def outer_method
  called_method
end

def called_method
  puts caller.first[/(?<=`).+(?=')/]
end

outer_method
# >> outer_method
```

A more modern and robust way is to do:

```
def outer_method
  called_method
end

def called_method
  puts caller_locations.first.label
end

outer_method
# >> outer_method
```

Comment: is that thing in primitive way Regex?

Comment: If you mean regex, or Regexp, then yes. It passes a regex to the method `[]`.